# Setting importance in email using xdmp:email

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am sending MarkLogic emails for monitoring details of a running host using `xdmp:email` through a scheduled job, I wanted to set the importance of the email based upon the status of the host from where the job is getting executed.

Please suggest how to go about it?

I want to set the importance as red if the system resources go below a particular benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can at all. The `xdmp:email` function relies on IETF standard for coding email messages as XML, see:

- https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/ and
- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-klyne-message-rfc822-xml-03

Neither speaks of a priority or importance flag or header, but I may have overlooked it..

HTH!